# Separating work and personal tabs in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

I am using my laptop for working and personal usage. I use usually many tabs for in my work and i keep using them for several days. Everyday in the afternoon when i want to use my laptop for personal stuff, i feel it's annoying to have the working tabs opened.

Thus, is there a way to have like two Firefox shortcuts in the desktop where when I open any of them, a group of tabs open?

I am looking for a solution that can keep track of the last tabs that were opened in each mode (e.g. working, personal).

Comment: I am being forced to use a personal laptop for work purposes; I have created a second user profile on the computer, which I use _only_ for work, and I _never_ use the "main" ID on that laptop for work.

Answer (score 4):

The standard solution from Firefox to isolate work and home tabs is to use [first party isolation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/first-party-isolation/) which separates cookies and local storage for different set of tabs. But that doesn't seems to be what you're looking for. What you describe would be easy to do using two [Firefox profiles](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/create-manage-multiple-profiles-firefox/).

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you the Firefox extension Simple Tab Groups. You can create groups (e.g. personal, work). If you open tabs in a group and then change the group, the visible tabs will be replaced with these from the newly selected group. Therefore it's easy to don't mix up personal and work stuff.

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups/

I'm not sure though, if it also separates the tabs in different containers, so they don't share cookies etc. If you want to do that, Firefox Multi-Account-Containers would be a solution. This add-on isolates different groups, so you can sign in with different accounts on the same website.

This can also hide/show tabs as you use it (seems tailored for what you're looking for):

> Hide and Show: Assume you use your browser for both Work and Personal tasks. When you come home at the end of the day, you don’t want to be thinking about “Work” anymore, but your browser is full of Work tabs. You can “Hide” your Work tabs and proceed with your Personal tasks. Then the next day, when you are back at work, you can “Hide” your Personal tabs and “Show” your Work tabs.

[More info @https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers#w_what-you-can-do-with-multi-account-containers]

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/

---

If you want even more separation, Firefox profiles could be the solution (like Riduidel mentioned). In this case, I recommend you to create a (Windows) shortcut for each profile:

```
C:\path\to\firefox.exe -P 'Profilename (e.g. work)'
```

You can set a custom icon and if you double click it, a new Firefox window with the specified profile will open.

Note, that with different profiles, most of the Firefox settings and all extension are separated as well.